# Some application pools are very slow at first load

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, application-pool

As stated in the [following article](http://forums.iis.net/p/1176520/2046929.aspx/1?p=True&t=635004973147926661), some .NET application pools become very slow (about x4 times) on first request. Problem concerns only Application Pools. Some of them are slow and some are not in the same conditions: web app, config, file permissions, etc.

> So my question is, how can this happen? How can one application pool become slower than the other application pool with identical settings, even after restarting both of them and is there a way to fix/prevent it? Once an application pool becomes slow, it does not become fast again, even with stopping and starting it.
>
> I made sure to recycle the application pools before every test i did, so that all tests were 'first requests'.

I've found the same problem and wonder if anyone here found solution for this weird problem?

Please notice that it's not the general problem of asp.net initialization speed. We comparing the same code on the same server with two app pools : generic (fast) and broken (slow). Switching two app pools (identical settings, but one unreasonable "slow") between two identical (the same) trivial (no any DB access, etc.) test asp.net applications  changing their behavior: one starts extremely slow, another - not.

The questions are:

- Why app pool becomes suddenly broken (slow)?
- How to avoid app pools become "slow"?
- How to fix broken app pools ? Yes, we could create
  unlimited new app pools , but anyway, it's weird and unacceptable for
  production environment.

UPD: I've noticed the problem even bounded not to the "slow" app pool itself, but to ITS NAME! If you rename "slow" app pools , it will became "fast" again. If you create new app pool named as previously renamed (or deleted) "slow" one, this app pool is slow again!

Comment: I experienced the same on a .NET 4 Integrated App Pool using Application Identity. What kind of identity did you use for the application pool that was slow?

Comment: I've experienced this issue in IIS 8.5 on a Windows 2012 Server. As OP stated, it's entirely related to the NAME of the app pool--once an app pool begins to have "issues" or poor performance, a new app pool with a different name must be created and used. I tested this by publishing the same API to two domains on one server, and two domains on another server for a total of 4 instances--they should have approximately the same performance as far as response times but the app pool in question always performed poorly until the pool was updated.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue where I had an app pool that was generating WCF errors saying it was in a faulted state. I tried creating a new app pool and testing the same code and it worked fine. I then deleted the old app pool and renamed the new one back to the old one and the issue returned! So it seems there's something being saved somewhere in relation to the app pool that doesn't get deleted when the app pool is deleted. Very strange.. By renaming it to anything else, it works again. But if I change it back to its original name, it throws the error! I just hope we don't have to keep changing the app pool names..

Comment: Still having that problem. Have you managed to find a solution, I wonder?

Answer (score 1):

Lol. This is kind of like when you get a pull lawnmower started. To do the initial requests and initialize the database it takes some time. We used to notice this every time we did an IIS Reset, on our sharepoint server. It has to take the web.config, connect to the data context or database, do a plethora of things before the site starts cranking out requests. Once running and having all the components and runtimes in place, though it's smooth. It's generally good to do maintanance that'll require an iisreset at night or off hours, so when a user first gets on, it's way quicker. Last thing you want is your CEO or VP, being the first one to access your site.

Also on a side note, the more Application Pools you have the more memory it takes. I know with SharePoint Application Pools, each pool takes 250MB of memory. The best bet to mitigate usage and resource consumption is to farm it out into a multiple web server farm/cluster that does some sort of round robbin or load balancing for requests. The more users that hit at a given point, the slower the the initial request will be.

Comment: Another thing I left out was NTFS security. Depending on whether you use integrated Windows Security or local passwords or KERBEROS/Certificates, or SSL with encryption on your site, also adds to the initial load time and overhead. Almost forget about security/authentication!

Comment: This all is generic and does not relate to the specific problem. Thanks for answer anyway. Agree, it's better to combine applications into one pool, it saves the memory. But reduces stability, on the other hand: if you pool crashed, all pooled applications will show up "Service unavailable" to your CEO or VP. )

Answer (score 0):

By default Application Pools are set to recycle after some period of time. I think default is 20 minutes. After recycling, things have to get re-loaded on the first request. That's probably what you're experiencing.